# Calculate land use percentage within an area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, land-use

I'm interested in calculating land use percentage for three layers (forest, agriculture and urban) within the context of a water basin area.

I've managed to merge the land use layers with Union tool and then clipped to the area of the basin. But having trouble thinking how to do it.

The result I'm thinking I want is an image showing the area with the three different land use polygon visible and then percentage in the attribute table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the area of the land use features by the area of the basin, then multiply by 100 to derive percent. If the area of your land use features or the basin are not already in the attribute table, you can derive it by creating a new field with a float field type and right clicking this field heading and selecting "Calculate Geometry".

Answer (score 0):

The total area of land in Mongolia is 1560000km2. The area of this land covered by water in
Mongolia is 10560km2.
(i) Calculate the percentage of land area covered by water in Mongolia

10560/1560000*100
=0.68%

Comment: How does this improve on the accepted answer?